# Exception in ExceptionFilterAttribute is always of type HttpResponseException

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api

Following [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/06/11/asp-net-web-api-exception-handling.aspx) on exception handling in the ASP.NET Web API, I created an `ExceptionFilterAttribute` that looks like this:

```
public class NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
        }
    }
}
```

... and an ASP.NET Web API controller that looks like this:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [NotImplExceptionFilter]
    public string Get()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This method is not implemented");
    }
}
```

The problem is that `context.Exception` is *always* of type `System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException` no matter what exception I throw in the `ActionMethod`.  As such, the code inside the `if` statement never gets executed.  The `Message` property on the exception is:

> Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see
>   the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this
>   exception for details.

The `Response` property referenced in the message is a `500 Internal Server Error`.

My routes are configured correctly because the `ActionMethod` does get hit.  I don't have any other `ExceptionFilterAttribute` filters applied.

Any idea how I can get the `context.Exception` to actually reference the exception that was thrown?

Comment: hmm..I was unable to repro your issue. What version of "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" package are you using?

Comment: 4.0.20710.0.  So you can't repo?  I was wondering if something else could be interfering with it. Any ideas on what that could be?  I don't even know where to start looking. Thanks for testing it though.

Comment: Turns out it was a logging package that was interfering with the `ExceptionFilterAttribute` (created internally within our organization).  I'm not sure what the package was actually doing but as soon as I removed it, I started receiving the correct exception type on the `HttpActionExecutedContext`.